# form wrapper is not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to design the signup form where there will be background of two sides with different color and the signup form should be just above that background and in the center. I could design the way i have explained but its not responsive enough. Mainly for the mobile design its not going well. For mobile devices there should be plain signup form only. May be I have done the mistakes in positioning(relative, absolute) part.

here is what i have done

html

```css
.signup-form {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.signup-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: #6493f3;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.left-block {
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  background: #6493f3;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}

.right-block {
  width: 560px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 50px 55px 55px 55px;
  position: relative;
}

form {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: -100px;
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.caption {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-field {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="signup-form">
  <div class="signup-wrapper">
    <div class="right-block">
      <form>
        <span class="caption">Create An Account</span>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="text" placeholder="full name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="text" placeholder="country" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="left-block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jsbin file is here either http://jsbin.com/ritinedeku/1/edit?html,css

Update

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.signup-form { 
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}


.signup-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  background: #6493f3;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.left-block{
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  background: #6493f3;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}

.right-block{
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

form {
        background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1.5px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
left: 0;
max-width: 450px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
padding: 20px;
z-index: 99;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 75%;
}

.caption {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-field {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="signup-form">
  <div class="signup-wrapper">
     <form>
        <span class="caption">Create An Account</span>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="text" placeholder="full name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <input type="text" placeholder="country" />
        </div>
      </form>
    <div class="right-block">
     
    </div>
    <div class="left-block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you make it an executable code, please?

Comment: Let me try wait pls

Comment: Code is now executable

Comment: The form doesn't look anything like the OP's example.

Comment: The purpose was to set the form\ in middle with both sides equal in left and right.

Comment: @WaqarAdil i don't think its responsive. Can you once check it, please?